# Bind more data to Telerik Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

There is a dropdown defined like this

```
@(Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
  .Name("Partners")
  .BindTo(@Model.AccountsList)
  .HtmlAttributes(attributes: new { @id = "partnerDropDown", @class = "stdDroplist" })
  .Placeholder(“Select”)
  .ClientEvents(events => events.OnClose("PartnerSelected")
)
```

//code behind

```
myList = (from account in myAccounts
          select new displayUX
          {
            Name = account.Name,
            Number = account.AccountNumber,
            CARCode = account.BTypeCode
          }).Distinct().ToList();

this.AccountsList = new SelectList(myList, "Name", "Number", selectedId);
```

//for your info, the System.Web.Mvc has

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue);
```

I want to pass on other data ‘CARCode’ for each item in the dropdown. So when the item is selected, apart from knowing the Number and Name, I would also need to know the ‘CARCode’. 
How can you pass the value and how to retrieve it.

Comment: You cant - unless you wanted to combine the `CARCode` with `Name` using a some separator so that you can split the selected value in your javascript or POST method). But why would you want to do this?

Comment: Based on the CARCode value of the selected item, we fetch records to be displayed in a list.

Comment: Then set the `dataValueField` of `SelectList` to "CARCode"

Comment: dataValueField and dataTextField is already taken by Name & Number respectively.

Comment: Then read my first comments again (you only have 2 properties that can be set - one for the options `value` attribute and one for its inner text.

Comment: That works, just that if there was better and elegant way of achieving this.